# trying to connect to the database, context = null

Tags: android, sqlite, android-context

Trying to connect to the database ; 
I have a problem `context = null` (may well must to be). I can not understand what the problem

```
import java.util.HashMap;

    import android.app.Activity;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class DatabaseTable extends Activity {

        private Context context;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.database_table);



            LBD conection = LBD.get(context);  // (context = null) ???
            Settings setting = new Settings(conection.getSQLiteDatabase());
            setting.create();


        }
    }
```

Comment: Give `context = DatabaseTable.this` after `setcontentView()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.database_table);

    context = DatabaseTable.this; // you can give this instead of DatabaseTable.this also.

    LBD conection = LBD.get(context);  // (context = null) ???
    Settings setting = new Settings(conection.getSQLiteDatabase());
    setting.create();
}
```

or you can give like -

```
    LBD conection = LBD.get(DatabaseTable.this);  // from this you don't need to Create any context instance of Context class. Directly pass the context here.
    Settings setting = new Settings(conection.getSQLiteDatabase());
    setting.create();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
context=this;//you forgot this...

LBD conection = LBD.get(context);  // (context = null) ???
Settings setting = new Settings(conection.getSQLiteDatabase());
setting.create();
```

Comment: db = (new OpenHelper(context)).getWritableDatabase() = nullpointerexception and context are no longer null

Answer (score 0):

Try  `LBD conection = LBD.get(this);`